# Do I need to enable billing for the Google Chat API or just create a service account?

Tags: google-chat

Does the google-chat-api service have a free tier for organizations?

In the tutorials it is mentioned that we have to create a cloud account and enable billing, which I was led to believe is not a necessity. In other docs its mentioned we just require a service account with no mention of billing. Therefore I am unclear as to whether this api is suitable for my purpose and constraints.

I shall be using it sparsely and in low volume, and only for in-house needs.

Comment: You should give the docs link that you talked about. But shortly, you don't need to enable billing account if you just want to use limited available endpoints. eg. If you want to use to automatic create message in chat space, you don't need to enable billing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no charge to enabling and configuring the Chat API and pointing the configuration at an endpoint not within the Google Cloud project.

**You do need a Google Workspace Domain at this time and I believe a billing account.**

*There could be very minor ancillary costs around logging errors.